# ASP.Net C# file download window stops a postback, and error messages stay in the repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

webpage allows user to download/ view a pdf file, after filling few data fields and choosing pdf type from ddl, so the problem I have is that there is a error repeater after all components and it shows errors and I can't clear the values, because postback doesn't happen.
So if I had a mistake prior to printing a PDF, that mistake stays in repeater and it's impossible to delete it. Because there is no postback when file download window appears...

Datetextbox

Datetextbox

ddl

button

errorRepeater

```
  protected void btnPrintPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

       if(DateTextbox'es !valid)
       {
          errors.add(new error);
       }
       if(ddl!selected)
       {
          errors.add(new error);
       }

       if(error.count==0){
         errors=null; //so if we had any errors before in the repeater,  
         errorRepeater=errors;//they Stay there and you can't delete them
         errorRepeater.databind();

         print.pdf(); //a download window jumps in browser killing postback
         //manually calling js postback from Codebehind doesn't work
}

protected void print.pdf(MemoryStream ms, string pdfName, string xslName)
        {
            ResourceContext xsltSert = new ResourceContext("/Path/xsl/" + xslName);
            Stream pdf;
            xsltSert.generatePdf(xmlInputStream: ms, pdf: out pdf);
            try
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpUtils.httpStream(Response, pdf, pdfName);
                Response.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                pdf.Close();
            }
        }
```

So far the only solution is to move validation's(add ontextchange events to dataTextBoxe's...) to a function outside buttonClick event, and if there are no mistakes then in buttonClick print pdf, lame way...

hope you can help

Greeed

Comment: Well a postback is the process of sending data back to the server, which is correctly does. When you call print.pdf it is modify the return data sent to the web browser. However we know nothing about print.pdf. What library are you using?

Comment: @Adam updated the lib, or wrote the printing procedure